# Node.js for PDF storage, viewing and download

Tags: node.js, backend

I am planning to write a web application that can store and serve large number of PDF files (average size per file is 5MB), expected total count is around 600,000 PDF files. May I ask if Node.js is the right framework to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node js is server side which will process your request to download and upload; These are the I/O operations so node.js is perfect for it. For storage of such number of files you should use AWS or a better platform for it.

Comment: Actually it is an old application built using VB.net in 2008 and never been updated. It is using an on-premise MS SQL server 2008. I am planning to use MongoDB this time, do you think its a good idea? Thank you.

Comment: Mongodb is good if you are storing JSON data or plain object data. In your case you can store file related information into collection like after uploading it on AWS you will get file info keys and other information so you can store that information.

Comment: again thank you, I'll put AWS as one my options.

Comment: @cauldyclark you are welcome. cheers. I am also using AWS for file/image storage with mongoDB. Hope my anser helped you.